# Regex for yyyymmdd to match an occurrence in a word

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have been trying to achieve this but nothing seems to achieve what I want. My requirement is very simple. I have a text line like this,

```
Your registration number is 201505260A61AIK01
```

This line contains the date 20150526 in format yyyymmdd. Now the line mentioned is one of many line in a text file. I am looking for a way to check if a text line contains YYYYMMDD pattern then retrieve the complete line. I have found dozens of regex but they all are not working. For example, the following regex,

```
 ^(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8]))))$
```

It matches when the string is,

```
Your registration number is 20150526
```

But not,

```
Your registration number is 201505260A61AIK01
```

I have searched for this a lot and will be amazed if this is found to be duplicate of another question because I didn't find any.

Comment: Remove `$` from the end.

Comment: And `^` from the start. However, you need to just match the first 8 digits, and then try to parse as `DateTime`.

Comment: Or replace `^` with `\b` if you require date pattern to be in the beginning of word.

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov Thanks. The pattern is mostly at the start but I am not sure if I found a line where it is not at the start. Will ^ handle every situation?

Comment: If the pattern may be in the middle of word, then, as @stribizhev said, you have to remove `^` complely. If the pattern is always in the beginning of word, then you have to replace `^` with `\b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using your long regex that is aimed at *validating* the datetime value as well as matching it in a longer string, you need to remove the start/end anchors:

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8]))))
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5B13579%5D%5B26%5D%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D)00)%7C(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5B13579%5D%5B26%5D)%7C(%3F%3A%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C0%5B48%5D))))(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A09%7C04%7C06%7C11)(%3F%3A0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D%7C30))%7C(%3F%3A(%3F%3A01%7C03%7C05%7C07%7C08%7C10%7C12)(%3F%3A0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D%7C3%5B01%5D))%7C(%3F%3A02(%3F%3A0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D))))%7C(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A09%7C04%7C06%7C11)(%3F%3A0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D%7C30))%7C(%3F%3A(%3F%3A01%7C03%7C05%7C07%7C08%7C10%7C12)(%3F%3A0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D%7C3%5B01%5D))%7C(%3F%3A02(%3F%3A%5B01%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-8%5D))))&i=Your%20registration%20number%20is%20201505260A61AIK01)

However, when dealing with DateTime values, you can use a simpler approach: match the numbers that are very similar to a datetime value and then try parsing them. The regex becomes mainatainable and readable:

```
(?<year>(?:20|19)\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})
```

Or even without that group break-up since we are not really interested in it in this approach:

```
(?:20|19)\d{6}
```

See the [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cyear%3E(%3F%3A20%7C19)%5Cd%7B2%7D)(%3F%3Cmonth%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D)(%3F%3Cday%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D)&i=Your%20registration%20number%20is%20201505260A61AIK01). It will work for us if we know there is a potential datetime in the string. Then, use `DateTime.Parse`:

```
Dim str As String ' First extract the string
str = Regex.Match(input, "(?<year>(?:20|19)\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})").Value
Dim dt As DateTime
Dim ok As Boolean = DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

The `dt` variable will contain the `DateTime` details if `ok` is `True` (i.e. if parsing was a success).

Comment: I am surprised. What is this second regex like statement you have written? Where ever I have found regex for date, it is very much long. This seems to be very short and I like this because I just need a match and don't want to extract the date and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the final `$`.

```
 ^(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8]))))
```

Comment: @Andrea Salicetti Thanks Wow such a simple thing and I spent so much time on this. Many thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I've stolen nothing, Sir, I master regexp and there were just one right answer, as you know.
I honestly read your answer after I posted my answer...

Comment: Why marking incorrect or poor answers as correct? I'd think twice as unaccepting an answer costs 2 points.

Comment: Cool down guys. Everyone has pointed out to same issue I had in my regex. All are right. I don't know what is this issue exactly but as this answer is the only available answer and solved my problem then I have to accept it. Or if there is some better solution then I can accept that as answer. It is not much of an issue I think. I thank all you guys.

Comment: I will post mine shortly.

Comment: I will be happy to upvote your answer - if it will be clear and right - @stribizhev, to underline my good faith, but please, let's stop the querelle: I just wanted to give my 5 cents quickly...

Comment: This regex now is working for the current input, but it is not correct because of at least `^` that will prevent the first alternative from matching datetime values. Have a look at the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vU4nG2/1), only the second alternative is what you are looking for here. It is much shorter than the whole expression. The 1st alternative (and it is a substantial piece of regex) is not used. Why maintain such a huge amount of patterns?